# Doctrine cascade persist from inversed side

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, cascade

I have a "many-to-many" relation with an association table. The function **calculDesCouts()**, from the parent table is calculating **the total cost of ingredients**, and persist this info in a field. Actually, because of the owning and inversed sides of the relations, I'm not able to cascade persist the parent table when an ingredient price has changed.

What is the proper way to do this? I mean, when a child row is updated, how to trigger the persist callback from the parent table? I know I can do it in my controller, with a loop on all recipes using this ingredient, but I would really like to do it on the ORM layer...

This is my parent entity, with a lifecycle callback on the calculDesCouts :

```
<?php

/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="recette")
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class Recette
{

  /**
   * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
   * @ORM\Id
   * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
   */
  private $id;

  /** 
   * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="\My\AcmeBundle\Entity\RecetteIngredientAssociation", mappedBy="recette", cascade={"persist"}) 
   */
  protected $recette_ingredient_associations;

  /**
   * @ORM\Column(type="decimal", scale=2, nullable=true)
   */
  private $cout_nourriture;

  /** 
   * @ORM\PrePersist
   * @ORM\PreUpdate
   */
  public function calculDesCouts()
  {
    $this->cout_nourriture = 0;

    foreach ($this->recette_ingredient_associations as $ria) {
      $this->cout_nourriture += $ria->getIngredient()->getPrix() * $ria->getQuantite();
    }

  }
}
```

This is my association entity:

```
<?php

/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="recette_ingredient_association")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class RecetteIngredientAssociation
{

  /**
   * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
   * @ORM\Id
   * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
   */
  private $id;

  /**
   * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="\My\AcmeBundle\Entity\Recette", inversedBy="recette_ingredient_association")
   * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="recette_id", referencedColumnName="id")
   *
   */
  private $recette;

  /**
   * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="\My\AcmeBundle\Entity\Ingredient", inversedBy="recette_ingredient_association")
   * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="ingredient_id", referencedColumnName="id")
   */
  private $ingredient;

  /**
   * @ORM\Column(type="decimal", scale=2, nullable=false)
   */
  private $quantite;

}
```

And this is my child entity:

```
<?php

/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="ingredient")
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class Ingredient
{

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="decimal", scale=2, nullable=true)
     */
    private $prix;

    /** 
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="\My\AcmeBundle\Entity\RecetteIngredientAssociation", mappedBy="ingredient") 
     */
    protected $recette_ingredient_associations;

}
```

Comment: It's not clear what do you want to archive.

Are you storing the total cost in database? If yes, it is not reflected in a code posted.
If no, and it's just calculated in a run every time when called, then I see no need to trigger anything. Every time when ingredient price is changed the total cost to the plate will reflect this change

Comment: I've updated the sample code from the parent entity with the $cout_nourriture column. Yes, the calculated field must be stored in the database, that's why it needs to be recalculated. (sorry for the bad english :( )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how to make it on ORM level, but I would do it on Symfony2 layer.
To make this what you need is to create an EventListener which will in case of Ingredient's update call Recette's calculDesCouts.

Like declare a service:

```
 app.ingredient_listener_update:
      class: AppBundle\Listener\IngredientPriceListener
      tags:
          - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: postUpdate }
```

and in this AppBundle\Listener\IngredientPriceListener make a method

```
public function postUpdate(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
{
    $entity = $args->getEntity();

    $em = $args->getEntityManager();

    if ($entity instanceof Ingredient) {

        foreach ($entity->get_recette_ingredient_associations() as $association) 
            foreach ($association->get_recettes() as $recette) {
                $recette->calculDesCouts();
                $em->persist($recette);
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I think its the best solution, and with a bit of changes on your code, it works fine!